# PHPExcel wrongly reading xls file as HTML

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, xls, php-stream-wrappers

I am using `PHPExcel` to read a large "xls" file. Firstly, I am determining the file type for reader using `PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName)`. However, PHPExcel is wrongly identifying it as HTML file and using HTML Reader which fails with DOM errors.

After some searching, I found that PHPExcel does not work well with stream wrappers. [Refer here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/429309).

I have no idea what stream wrappers are, and the file I am trying to read is downloaded using wget.

Please let me know how to remove the stream wrappers, so that PHPExcel can identify the file correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Be careful with the excel filename : PHPExcel does not like special characters like accentued ones.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file to a local drive on your server, even if just as a temporary file, then try to identify/read it.... but PHPExcel uses [fseek()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) for most of its Readers, which isn't supported by many of the stream wrappers.

Comment: File is on local drive but still it fails.

Comment: In that case, take a close look at the file in a text editor and see what it actually contains.... PHPExcel will only tell you it's `HTML` if it contains markup

Comment: Its a simple xls file, opens in MS Excel, no HTML markup at all.

Comment: I said open in a text editor.... MS Excel is quite capable of opening HTML files, even if they have an extension of .xls; but PHPExcel will not arbitrarily tell you that a file is `HTML` if it doesn't contain markup, as a worst case it might tell you that it's `CSV`, but not `HTML`

Comment: Also, can you provide a link to the file that's being misinterpreted.... if I'm going to spend several hours trying to track down and fix a potential bug in PHPExcel, I want something to actual demonstrate that bug so that I can test and see if any changes I make fix it

Comment: I checked, it contains the data in html table format, how do I parse it in PHPExcel and get final CSV.

Comment: You use the HTML Reader that PHPExcel recommends via identify() to load the file, then the CSV Writer to save as a csv file

Comment: Already tried but it to fails load the file, any other suggestion?